# PHP Session with a Language and Flat-File

Tags: php, session, flat-file

Please excuse my English language skills. 
I have a Homepage with a language exchange in the following included common.php

```
    <?php
session_start();
header('Cache-control: private');
if(isSet($_GET['lang']))
{
$lang = $_GET['lang'];
$_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;
setcookie('lang', $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
} else if(isSet($_SESSION['lang'])) {
$lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
} else if(isSet($_COOKIE['lang'])) {
$lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
} else {
$lang = 'de';
}

switch ($lang) {
case 'en': $lang_file = 'lang.en.php'; break;
case 'de': $lang_file = 'lang.de.php'; break;
case 'ru': $lang_file = 'lang.ru.php'; break;
case 'fr': $lang_file = 'lang.fr.php'; break;
default: $lang_file = 'lang.de.php';
} 
include_once 'lang/'.$lang_file;
?>
```

Now I would like to implement on my website a Mini-Blog with Flat Files and use the following Code

```
  <?php
   define("DEFAULT_LANGUAGE", "lang=de");
   session_start();
   $languages = ["de", "en", "fr", "ru"];
   if( isset($_GET["lang"]) ){ $lang = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "lang", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
   if( !in_array($lang, $languages) ){ $lang = DEFAULT_LANGUAGE; }
     $_SESSION["language"] = $lang;
   }
   function get_lang() { return isset($_SESSION["language"]) ? $_SESSION["language"] : DEFAULT_LANGUAGE; }
   function get_post_names() {
   static $_cache = [];
   if(empty($_cache)){ $_cache = array_reverse(glob(__DIR__ . '/posts/' . get_lang() . '/*.php')); }
   return $_cache;  
   }
   function print_posts() { $paths = get_post_names();
   foreach( $paths as $path ){ $content = file_get_contents($path);
   echo "<div class='post'>\n";
   echo "<p>{$content}</p>\n";
   echo "</div>\n\n";
     }  
   }
   ?>
   <?php print_posts(); ?>
```

For the blog posts, there is a folder [posts] in which subfolders (de, en, fr, ru). In these subfolders there are, depending on the language, for example: "examplepost.php" in whose blog posts have been written.
The language selection works without any problems. But I want that when a user selects a different language, then the Blog automatically reads the voice corresponding folder of the blog and containing the outputs files.

The Problem is that there are two Sessions. This leads to errors! My question would be: How can I merge everything together in a Session or how can I connect the two Sessions without conflicts, so it works both (the language of the site and the output of the files in the folders of the visitors selected language for the Blog posts).

Many thanks in advance to all of you for your help and suggestions! Greeting

Answer (score 1):

You do not need two sessions to hold the same variable ($lang).
What you can do is something like this:

```
session_start();
// check/set default language session    
if (!isset($_SESSION["language"])) {
$_SESSION["language"] = DEFAULT_LANGUAGE;
}
if ($isset($_GET['lang']) && in_array($_GET['lang'], $languages) ){
$_SESSION["language"] = $_GET['lang'];
}
// execute more code
$lang_file = 'lang.'.$_SESSION["language"].'.php';
include_once 'lang/'.$lang_file;
```

Comment: Thank you for Your answer! But I need the connection to the sub-folders (see the PHP Script) in your Script. For example, with ...

    require_once("posts/" . $lang . "*.php");

In the sub-folders there are four folders: DE, EN, FR, RU. The there containing .php files must, depending on the language selection, the content displayed is read out with <a href="index.php?lang=de">German</a> 
Just how is it possible that both work?

Comment: @php_echo have your include file below session declaration, as i have demonstrate in my exxample. First find what language you will use (eitehr default or GET, then assign it to session, thn include proper folders/files

Answer (score 0):

[andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/701961/andrew)
I think I have expressed myself wrong. 
The common.php for the language exchange, is responsible and should be retained. I just need a function in the common.php what are the same functions as in the other mentioned Script. It must be possible, that ...

- is changed to the selected language on the website
- And at the same time also referred to the sub-folder of the blog ("posts").

**The Structure**

```
[root]
|_ acp ........ admin-center
|_ css ........ css styles
|_ img ........ graphics
|_ inc ........ includes files
|_ func ....... function files (i.e. common.php)
|_ js ......... js files
|_ lang ....... language files
|_ posts ...... for the Blog Postings 
  |_ [de] [en] [fr] [ru]
```

In the last Folders are .php files witch, depending on the language selection has been selected via the common.php at the same time with the common.php also the files of the [posts] folder of the blog and displayed to be read.

In short ... 1) depending on the language in the language file redirect - AND - 2) in addition to the sub-folder of the [posts] folder and the contained files to be read and the contents of the files output.